# Need to add single line at beginning of every PHP file?

Tags: php, recursion, regex

Wondering if there's a quick way to recursively find every file ending in .php and add this line at the beginning..

```
<? $DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/html';?>
```

Have tried register_globals etc and no ball so this looks like the easiest way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Voted to migrate to SO... That said, this is a bad idea. You don't want to hard-code this value in the top of every file. You want to add a reference to a single config file where it's set. I know it's unlikely to change, but it's a configuration value, and configuration values should be kept in one place, not splattered throughout your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

```
$path = "somedir/";    

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$regex     = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach($regex as $file) { 
    $file     = $file[0];       
    $contents = 
        "<?php $DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/html';?>\n" 
        . file_get_contents($file);    

    file_put_contents($file, $contents);        
}
```

I have no idea how it will perform for lots of files, use wisely. By the way, you should [avoid the short open tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) and always use `<?php`.

---

I've answered the question before it was updated to include `"<?php $DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/html';?>\n"` as the line needed in every file. It's a bad idea, as @DanRay commented:

> You don't want to hard-code this value in the top of every file. You want to add a reference to a single config file where it's set. I know it's unlikely to change, but it's a configuration value, and configuration values should be kept in one place, not splattered throughout your codebase.

---

Alternative implementation without `RegexIterator`:

```
$path = "somedir/";    

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);

foreach($iterator as $file) {
    $path = $file->getRealPath();

    if(
        !$file->isFile()
        || !preg_match('/^.+\.php$/i', $path)
    ) {
        continue;
    }

    $contents = 
        "<? $DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/html';?>\n" 
        . file_get_contents($path);    

    file_put_contents($path, $contents); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it's bad practise, it's a quick fix before the TTL expires and the domain ticks over. Much appreciated!

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RegexIterator' not found in  :(, I guess my PHP version is too old for this.

Comment: @Max I've updated the answer to not use `RegexIterator`, which has been on at least since PHP 5.1, you really need to upgrade your php version.

Answer (score 2):

With PHP 4.2.3+ you could simply use the PHP directive [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

For example in your `php.ini`:

```
auto_prepend_file = /var/www/html/myproject/myprepend.php
```

Another possibility would be to use the directive in `.htaccess` files:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/html/myproject/myprepend.php
```

where /var/www/html/myproject/myprepend.php (or whatever path you use) just contains

```
<?php
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/html';
```